# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$user_id

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm just a beginner at laravel, Sorry if it's a stupid question

**Here's my controller :-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Profile;
use Auth;



class ProfilesController extends Controller
{

  public function _construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function create()
  {
    return view('bio');
  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
  auth()->user()->profile()->user_id;
    // create Bio
    $profile = new Profile;

    $profile->bio = $request->input('bio');
    $profile->save();
    return redirect('/home');

  }


}
```

**Here's My Model:-**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
  protected $gaurded = [];
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'bio'];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Here Are My Tables**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
  protected $gaurded = [];
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'bio'];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Here's My User Model:-**

```
  public function profile()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Posts::class);
    }
```

I'm getting this error **"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$user_id"** I don't know where i went wrong please help me and guide me if u can 
**Thanks**

Comment: fyi, typo in `$gaurded`. What is `auth()->user()->profile()->user_id;` supposed to do?

Comment: `auth()->user()->profile->user_id;` instead of `auth()->user()->profile()->user_id;`

Comment: As you said @TsaiKoga i tried **"auth()->user()->profile->user_id;"** but the error i got is this **"Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object "**

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox because the profile is none, it means the user has no profile. Why don't u just use `$id = auth()->id();`

Comment: This is what i got **"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value"**  i'm new to coding as well so i'm sorry if you are pissed by my stupidity

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox I'm not pissed, bro. I have post the answer, you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call the attribute `user_id` on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne` `profile()`,

you can call it by `auth()->user()->profile->user_id`.

However, the user has no profile yet. Need to create it and use [create](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne`, Laravel will automatically build the foreign_key `user_id` to `profile`.

```php
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      auth()->user()->profile()->create([
         'bio' => $request->input('bio')
      ]);
      return redirect('/home');
  }
```

Comment: THAAAAANNKKSS bro.... i know its too much to ask but can we communicate some how so that you can guide me through in future..

Answer (score 1):

**In your Profile model**

```
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class,"user_id","id");
}
```

In your Controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
       echo $id = auth()->user->profile->user_id; 
       $input = $request->all();
       $input['user_id'] = auth()->id(); // OR auth()->user->profile->user_id;
       Profile::create($input);
       return redirect('/home');
  }
```

Comment: it shows **"Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user "** error

Comment: check updated answer `$input['user_id'] = auth()->id(); `

Comment: thanks for the reply... i have found the solution the "i was not creating the profile in there"

Comment: Please select this answer :)

Comment: if you want  me to i will

Answer (score 0):

you need to define foreign key and local key in relation in user model as this:

```
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class,"user_id","id");
}
```

Comment: it shows **"Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user"** error

Comment: let me see your code in user model and controller  , i tried  it and work with me

Comment: i've added the User model in my question and i have already received the answer the create command was missing  Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your goal is to define a one to one relationship.

For that matter you need to define a hasOne relationship in user model

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

and a belongsTo in profile model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and don't forget to put the user_id in your profile table.

check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for more info

After these steps if you have a logged in (authenticated) user, you could get the user_id field of profile table with this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


Auth::user()->profile->user_id;
```

Comment: Yes i've already done that relationship thing and as you said i have changed it to **"auth()->user->profile->user_id; "** but it still shows this error **"Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user "**

Comment: ok i found the solution, your syntax for getting information about authenticated user should be like this: Auth::user()->Profile->user_id; Auth is Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

Comment: Thanks for the reply But i have found the solution, i was not creating the profile thats the reason i was unable to pass the data Thanks Again